# Update mongo driver to mongoldb driver in ubuntu

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Currently mongo driver is being displayed in phpinfo file in ubuntu.

I have installed mongo and mongodb drivers for Laravel 5.3 and PHP 5.6.30 but I want to configure mongodb driver in phpinfo in ubuntu.

Comment: Seeing as Laravel 5.6 doesn't exist you may want to update your version description.

Comment: @alaric, updated